# value from dropdown show/hides div and keeps its state

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, show-hide

im relatively new to ROR, and would like some help with the following code.

I would like to show a div (it's called demographics) when a specific selection ("Customers") is made form a dropdown. If an option other than "Customers" is selected from the dropdown, I would like that the demographicsv div remain hidden.

At present, my code is partially working. It shows and hides the div; however, when I save the page and come back to it, the div is hidden, even if "Customers" is selected in the dropdown. This might be because the default setting is: display:none.

Is there a way to make sure that the field is displayed on page load when the proper selection has been made?? And I suppose a way to make the opposite true too--> a div with display:block; remains hidden if the field from the dropdown does not match the required field.

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank you and I sincerely appreciate your time:

my code (HAML):

```
= f.select :who, WHO, {}, :onChange => "showDemographics(this)", :prompt => true

#demographics{:style => "display:none;"}
  %p.information
    please fill out the following demographics.
  %div{:class => "label_leftalign field"}
    = f.label :age, "Age"
    = f.select :age, AGES, :prompt => true
  %div{:class => "label_leftalign field"}
    = f.label :race, 
    = f.select :race, RACES, :prompt => true
```

Javascript

```
  function showDemographics(obj)
  {
    if(obj[obj.selectedIndex].value == 'Customer')
    {
        document.getElementById('demographics').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('demographics').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

EDIT::
OK, So the key issue is that on page reload a div remains hidden even if the correct value is in the dropdown box. I suppose that this can be solved by one of two ways 1. running some sort of validation on everytime the page is loaded or 2. cookies.

Unfortunately, I'm not very well versed in Javascript or jQuery... and I've never implemented cookies on a site, and would prefer to avoid using them if possible.

Could anyone help me write a script that validates the presence of Customer in the dropdown and shows/hides a div accordingly? Thank you, and thanks to Carlos Pardilla and M. Cypher for their help thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers above where correct in their own way... the link below shows the actual code that is required for the conditional statement on page load:

[show hidden divs on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937328/show-hidden-divs-on-refresh-rails-javacript)

Answer (score 3):

You have tagged the question with jQuery although you're not using it in the code, but I'll just assume it's fine if I give you some jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#who').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Customer') {
      $('demographics').show();
    } else {
      $('demographics').hide();
    }
  }).change();
}
```

Note that you need to give the `select` an `id` (in this case `who`) for it to work.

Comment: I'm sorry... this did not work for me. should I have changed something in the HAML to trigger the jquery function? thank you for your time

Comment: you have to add jquery to your rails app first if you haven't done so yet. use the `jquery-rails` gem. but of course you could do the same in pure javascript, it's just more complicated. i really recommend you read more about jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a conditional statement to be checked during page load. You could establish the visibility (or lack thereof) of the div depending on the value ("Customers") of the option:selected element within your select object (the dropdown). Maybe via a script on the head of the document (provided it is a short script). Also, by doing this you wouldn't need to set the display property from the start. It would fire depending on the selected condition during page load.

This could be done to get the opposite result as well, as you said.

Hope it'll help!

Comment: Carlos, this makes sense, however, i'm not sure how I would do this (ie: dont know what code to write). But yes, you are right... this appears logical.

Comment: Hope this'll help: http://jsfiddle.net/CarlosPF/8Y5QP/ Just copy-paste selected="selected" in-between options and see how the div is visible or not depending on the executed condition.

Comment: You have, of course, to run the method everytime you do that to see how it happens on page load.

Comment: Carlos, unfortunately I cant add that code as my option fields are housed in Constants.rb and not available in HAML... unless there is a way to code around this issue.

Comment: As I am not familiar with your project I would suggest putting this code into a .js file and then referencing this file in your application's main view (the one erb file in your views/layouts folder). By referencing this javascript file throughout your whole app, you should be able to interact with the DOM in any way you see fit. On the other hand, I'm not familar with HAML myself and maybe I'm assuming too much about the way everything is configured. But, well, you get the idea.